# Estimation of camera displacement

Tags: math, image-processing, computer-vision, multiple-views

I am currently working on a experiment that i took multiple photos
of a scene on diferent days with a fixed camera position.
The problem is that on real world it is hard to keep the camera
perfectly fixed.

What i need is to fix the small variance I got automaticaly. The research
I made returned methods considering more complex assumption, like camera
pose estimation, homography estimation etc.
For me its enought to discover just the movement at the image plane returning an
x and y. 
A perfect solution would be a function such as:

function [movx movy] = detectMotion(im1,im2).

The solution I already made was to calculate some image features, like harris or
hessian, match them and after manualy select the best ones and use the difference
of their position as a camera displacement estimation. I dont know if this is good
enough but it would be better if it was made automaticaly.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the feature matching automatically be extracting feature descriptors around the interest points. Take a look at this OpenCV tutorial on how to perform [feature matching using SURF and FLANN](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html). Once you have the feature matches, run RANSAC or least squares to find the best fit for an x- and y-offset. This will give you a decent estimate of the camera motion.

Another option is to compute [sparse optical flow](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk) on the detected interest points between the two frames, followed by the RANSAC or least squares procedure as above to compute the best x- and y-offset. [Dense optical flow](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowfarneback) could possibly be more accurate, but at the same time could prove to be overkill.